# What happens to differential backups when Copy Only backup is restored?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have a database (Sql Server 2014) that is set up to do periodic full and more frequent differential backups; I need to migrate that database and restore it if migration failed. To prevent any data loss, I am going to back up the database before I try migrating it.

I understand that I should not do a full backup because it will affect subsequent differentials. If I do a copy only backup that gets prevented. However, if I do a restore using the copy only backup, will subsequent differentials work and be restorable? I did an experiment with a smaller database and I noticed that while restoring the copy only backup changed the DatabaseBackupLSN, I was still able to do differentials, and was also able to use them to restore the database (combining the differential with a full backup taken beforehand). However I haven't found anything confirming that this will work in all cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why take an out of band backup at all? That is, why not use one the existing full backups?

Comment: I am also evaluating that as an option...I could tap into the stored procedures the scheduled backups are created with and trigger a differential backup right before I do the migration, then restore using those same backups. I'm hesitating to use this option because those scripts are not under my control and it adds another bit of complexity where I have to coordinate with the team that owns those scripts.

Comment: I'm assuming your hiding "migrating" as a term meaning "move to another server". Also, what recovery model is your database in?

Comment: No, it's a schema migration with some minor data updates, as a part of installing a new version of the software that goes along with it. Database is in simple recovery model.

Comment: Just in case someone finds it...even though my findings indicated that restoring a copy only backup wouldn't affect the backup chain, I ended up using the option I mentioned in the comment above. So this question is unanswered ~

Answer (score 0):

Differentials contain all data pages modified since the last full backup, so they can only be used for restores together with the last full backup. Eg if you have the following sequence of events:

1. Perform a database full backup
2. Make changes in the database
3. Perform a copy-only backup
4. Make more changes in the database
5. Perform a diff backup

If you had to restore the database from these backups, restoring the full backup from 1 and the diff backup from 5 would restore your DB to its state at step 5. If you **only** had the full backup you could only restore to step 1, and if you **only** had the diff you couldn't restore anything (as the diff would be relative to the missing full backup). If you only had the copy-only backup and the diff backup, you could restore the copy-only backup and you would be restored to the state at step 3, but you could not use the diff as it is relative to the missing full backup.

So to answer your question, if you restored from a copy-only backup, you could still take diff backups, but they would only be usable when combined with the last **full** backup. The main purpose of copy-only backups is to allow backups to be taken without invalidating the last full backup required by differentials.